# Changing the WordPress site url according to the geographical locations of the users

Tags: wordpress

I own a multi-language WordPress site. I want when a user from the Middle East clicks on the link to automatically go to the Arabic version
For example, a user from the Middle East clicks on the following link example.com  It will automatically move to this link example.com/ar/
how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

**Polylang**
If you have polylang installed, the best approach I now is to go to settings set the following:

*Url Modifications > (Uncheck) Hide URL language information for default*

*(Activate) Detect browser language*

This will change the page according to the language of their browsers.

Comment: Thank you, but the site is ready in languages and I used Polylang and the site is ready.
The problem is that the main language on the site is English. I need to make a redirect when opening the site for the Arabic version only for users from the Middle East

Comment: Try the settings I wrote in the edited answer. This will half-achieve what you want.